# Returning to a literal field in a SQL Snippet

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, code-snippets

I am tasked with creating SQL snippets for several of our most commonly used stored procedures.  For the most part all of our procedures are pretty uniformed to each other.  I was wondering is there a way for the user to have the literal fields reappear, if they were to hit the Enter Key?  For example, from the screenshot, what if I wanted to put a second parameter on the line under @param1.  When I hit enter the literal fields (those is yellow that can be tabbed) disappear.  I am sure this is something easy but I have not been able to find a way to enter new sql after hitting the enter key, is there something that I can do other than hitting ENTER?

[image]

Update 8/2:
Let say that I want to have an extra Parameter (weight) along with height included in my procedure.  My snippet only gives me an option of having 1 parameter field (field = yellowish block).
[image: Before hitting ENTER]

When I type in Height followed by a comma and hit ENTER to go to the next line to type the Weight parameter, the yellow blocks disappear and my cursor ends up at the bottom of the script (second screen shot).  I wish to leave the Yellow highlighted areas to add additional objects, if needed, and return to them.  Notice how the the Insert statement no longer has the Column and Value yellow highlights?
[image: After typing 1st parameter with comma and hitting ENTER to add Weight parameter]

Comment: Do you really always use READ UNCOMMITTED? Do you know that when you do that you can and will get missing and/or duplicate rows? http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 0):

Q. what you mean disappear? is that mean red dotted or totally disappears?

if it has already procedure named stage.hello then you should write 'ALTER' instead of 'CREATE'

Comment: I have posted a larger before and after screen shot of my snippet, hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: Also the snippet will only be used when Creating the procedure from the beginning.